# Joining two MultiIndex DataFrames with different number of index levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, multi-index

I have a `pandas` dataframe:

```
                               emp    laborforce  emp_rate
occ statefip quarter                                      
10  1        0        6.561213e+06  7.017537e+06  0.934974
             4        8.580723e+06  9.114996e+06  0.941385
             8        8.588012e+06  9.102831e+06  0.943444
             12       2.093297e+06  2.220923e+06  0.942535
    2        0        6.561208e+06  7.017527e+06  0.934974
```

Now I want to merge into this dataset the average `emp_rate` for each `(occ, statefip)`. I tried

```
df2 = df1.groupby(level=[0, 1])['emp_rate'].mean()
df2.name = 'emp_rate_mean'
df1.join(df2, how='inner')
NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented
```

Apparently, this type of `join` would work since `pandas` 0.14 if the second dataframe was single-indexed. It is not. What's the proper approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [GroupBy.transform()](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [102]: df['emp_rate_avg'] = df.groupby(level=[0, 1])['emp_rate'].transform('mean')

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
                             emp  laborforce  emp_rate  emp_rate_avg
occ  statefip quarter
10.0 1.0      0        6561213.0   7017537.0  0.934974      0.940584
              4        8580723.0   9114996.0  0.941385      0.940584
              8        8588012.0   9102831.0  0.943444      0.940584
              12       2093297.0   2220923.0  0.942535      0.940584
     2.0      0        6561208.0   7017527.0  0.934974      0.934974
```

Comment: So this circumvents the problem by suggesting `transform()` and never "loosing" the dimension in the index. What if I was given the `.mean()` dataset and had to somehow merge it?

Comment: @FooBar, `df1.reset_index('quarter').join(df2).set_index('quarter', append=True)` - I don't know a better/more efficient approach...